# getSharedPreferences(name: "database") Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This is my first time developing an android app. 
I get an error in the line - getSharedPreferences(name: "database", )

saying it's an unresolved reference name. Is there something else I should declare or initialize.

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        btn_addinventory.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this,AddProductActivity::class.java))
        }
        getSharedPreferences(name: "database", )

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't include the parameter name; just `getSharedPreferences("database", ...`. You're apparently copying code from an image or video that shows an IDE with parameter name hints enabled. Those don't actually go in your code.

Comment: @MikeM. I just realized that. Yes, I am following a video tutorial. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        btn_addinventory.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this,AddProductActivity::class.java))
        }
        getSharedPreferences("database",Context.MODE_PRIVATE )

    }

}
```